# Can't boot to Windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I wanted to try out Ubuntu. So I thought of dual booting with my Windows 10. The problem is that I forgot to turn off fast startup in Windows. So now grub is not showing Windows. Is there any way to get my Windows back?

Answer (score 0):

It's a 'duel', all right! Insert the Windows install disk, reboot into it and choose Repair Windows option. Wait for it to finish, then reboot (and remove Windows installation disk).

Now, you will only see Windows at startup. Boot into Windows and disable Fast Startup.

Insert the Ubuntu installation disk and reboot (yes, again!). Boot into a Live Ubuntu session, open a Terminal window and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

If everything worked good, now you should have GRUB menu with both Ubuntu and Win options. You can find more details about this procedure here:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair.

Alternatively, you could try to install 'grub-customizer' and edit the list of operating systems. Find more here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-16-04-lts/.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. but the problem is that i don't have my windows install disk. is there any other way to get it back from ubuntu itself?

Comment: Because you are using windows 10, you can easily download an official Windows.iso file from Windows: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/software-download/techbench

Just download and then make a live cd or live usb from that iso file.

Comment: @Sidharth Sajeev: Check the last line of the (edited) answer. Maybe grub-customizer could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the EFI menu (some function key at power-up, varies by machine) to select boot device/os and select Windows. Some machines may have a two stage menu, select hard disk first, then select Windows.  Turn off the power-option "fast boot", and reboot to Ubuntu, then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and you should see The Windows choice in grub.  Note, you still have to have secure boot disabled to boot Windows 10 from Grub.